# Not able to make a tab work as 2 pages in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 App and I have added the tabs theme and I want one of the tabs to work as 2 routing like when the user is not login, login page will open and when the user is login the account page will open.

This is my **tabs.router.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from '../guards/authentication.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2/:id',
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'acceptchallenge',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../acceptchallenge/acceptchallenge.module#AcceptchallengePageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
          },
          {
            path: '/login',
            loadChildren: '../login/login.module#LoginPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

I want to tab3 to open the login page when the user is not login and when the user is login open the account page.

So I have to add any `canActivate` for this to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest to build a login page and once authenticated direct to your tab structure, setting the account page as root.

Comment: @JayOrdway. I have a login page and once authenticated it will redirect to tabs page but the problem is that when the user opens the login page no back button is there? So, Can you help me with that?

Comment: Don't route to your login page without logout function. if user logout then redirect user to login page. but don't let them go to login page without logout function.

Comment: @Najamussaqib. Yes that is happening. When the user is not login, he can visit the login page and when the user is login he can not visit the login page but I want to show the login page on the tab3 and account page also on tab3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `tabs.html`
you can use *ngIf to show tabs when user log-in or logout. Take a bool or whatsever logic you can use and show it in your tabs page like this.

```
<ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="profile" *ngIf="userLogin == true">
      <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="login"  *ngIf="userLogin == false">
      <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Login</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
</ion-tab-bar>
```